# Unexpected token chaining operator expression when cypress file:preprocessor reads a fork

Tags: javascript, webpack, cypress

Hey I have a JS expression that I don't know name of does somone know how is this called in theory?

```
return defaultScreenshotOptions?.errorThreshold || 0;
```

Full error message

```
 Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./node_modules/cypress-visual-regression/src/command.js 14:34
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (14:34)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   }
|
>   return defaultScreenshotOptions?.errorThreshold || 0;
| }
|
```

My other question is about the webpack loaders that are needed  to parse this module.

Comment: If you mean `?.` that's _optional chaining_ per e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/3001761.

Comment: thanks that's exaclty what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Reason to this error is `return defaultScreenshotOptions?.errorThreshold || 0;` a optional chaining operator expression is ES2020 feature thus is not supported by default file:preprocessor. Pass default options listed in package documentation.

```
module.exports = (on) => {
  const options = {
    // options here
  }

  on('file:preprocessor', browserify(options))
}
```

The **solution to this error is to configure browserify-preprocessor** for cypress. The default options for browserify are applaying ES2020 features.

[npm package @cypress/browserify-preprocessor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cypress/browserify-preprocessor)